# Gradle: Modify source sets according tasks

Tags: gradle

Currently, I'm creating several artifacts according its target environment:

```
task createDevelopmentWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {...}
task createQAWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {...}
task createProductionWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {...}
```

It's working fine for me by now, nevertheless, all the artifacts are created using the same java source sets. I'd like to modify the source set of each task according its target environment.

Currently I'm getting this commenting or uncommenting this code:

```
compileJava {
    excludes = ['**/aspects']
}
```

So, when I want to generate production artifact, I comment it.

I'm sure there's an more elegant way to make it possible attaching peace of code into each task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [gradle-java-flavours](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours) plugin where you could create `flavours` for `development`, `qa` and `production` and have specific java source, resources and tests for each (on top of common sources).

The plugin doesn't currently create a `War` task for each `flavour` but this could be done in a similar way to the [jar task](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursExtension.groovy#L55)